# Too many getattr requests for file info when using nfs

Tags: nfs, getattr

I'm sharing a folder using nfs on a Linux system. It's very slow, and I found that there are many getattr requests.

After I mount my shared nfs folder on another machine, I'm trying to copy the files out. It's very slow. What I found via tcpdump is lots of getattr calls happening. Most of the requests are on the same file, which I don't understand either.

This is the mount command I'm using:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,bg,hard,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,vers=3,nointr,timeo=600,actimeo=0,nolock,tcp

content of /etc/exportfs:
/dept/nfs *(no_subtree_check,rw,async)
```

What is the possible reason why there are so many getattr calls?
Is there any configuration problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the mount option: **actimeo=0**. This disables attribute caching on the client, which will send getattr requests to the server.